# Algo to remember a series of GUIDs

Tags: algorithm, sorting, data-structures

Here the scenario:
everyday I receive a message. the message is containing an Identifier made of GUID 128 bit and the date it was sent.

Now, I need a way to check if a message I receive was received already in the last 14 days.

The thing is everyday I receive millions of mails and to remember each and every GUID as it is is too much... is there a way to manipulate this data so I can remember it it the most minimum space?

Thought about using Bloom filter but it won't work because of the require of fixed size...

Would appreciate any input,

Thank you

Comment: How many millions per day, more like 999 millions or more like 1.1 millions ? And what is the probability that a mail is a duplicate ?

Comment: A GUID is only 16 bytes when stored as a binary value (as opposed to a hexadecimal string) so 3m per day for 14 days is ~580mb, is theare a problem with that?

Comment: Why is the fixed size requirement of Bloom filter a problem? Also, understand that Bloom filter by design is subject to false positives (telling you that a GUID was received even though it hasn't been). You can adjust the false positive rate to make it exceedingly rare, but you can't eliminate false positives entirely.